# how to retrive the last value from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have an arduino thats pushing readings to the database and i have an android app that retrieve the readings and show it in a textView.

[image]

My app keeps getting everything the keys and the values to the textView .

How can i solve this issue and show only last value?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Initialize Firebase App
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

    // Inflate layout
    Binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing)

    // Initialize Firebase Database query
    val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://voltageread-22aa9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/")
        .reference
        .orderByKey()
        .limitToLast(1)

    // Fetch data from Firebase Realtime Database and save it in a variable
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists() && snapshot.value != null) {
                val lastChildSnapshot = snapshot.children.lastOrNull()
                if (lastChildSnapshot != null) {
                    val data = lastChildSnapshot.value.toString()
                    if (!data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        Log.d("Firebase", "Data received: $data ")
                        // Update the UI with the received data
                        Binding.voltage.text = data.substringAfter('=')
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("Firebase", "Data fetching cancelled: ${error.message}  ")
        }
    })
```

tried using the built in fucrions but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use query operations such as `orderByKey` and `limitToLast` in Firebase, they operate on the direct child nodes of the path in the database that you refer. Since you operate on the root of the database, the keys under that are ordered and filtered, leaving you with one child key: `all`.

What you want to do instead is operation on the `all` path itself, so that Firebase orders and filter the `-N...` child nodes you have under there. In code that'd be:

```
val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://voltageread-22aa9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/")
    .reference
    .child("all") // 
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(1)
```